# What does "anything but ho-ho-hum" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean increasing?

Traffic and sales this year at tree outlets have been anything but ho-ho-hum. Merchants are reporting a big season that started early and has continued to accelerate into the early part of December.

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2020/12/03/christmas-tree-sales-are-telling-a-holly-jolly-economic-story.html

Comment: Please see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ho-hum). I think it's a poor use, because Father Christmas says "Ho ho" to be jolly, which contradicts  the story.

Comment: Have you [looked it up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/ho-hum)?

Comment: I think **ho-ho-hum** is supposed to be a fusion of **ho-ho** (Father Chistmas laughing) and **ho-hum** (boring) but IMO it does not 'come off' as seen by asking the question. They are sort-of opposites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pun.

- "Ho hum" is an English interjection used to express *boredom*.
- "Ho ho ho" is an expression synonymous with Christmas, as Santa Claus is often portrayed as laughing in this manner".

So "*ho-ho-hum*" suggests Christmas-related boredom, or possibly just something boring in a Christmas-related article.

In effect, it is saying:

> Traffic and sales this year at tree outlets have been *anything but boring*.